# Firebase security rules based on custom user field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up security rules (use Firebase Cloud Firestore).

I changed the "users" table (added company_id field) and create "appointments" table (with company_id). I want to implement the following functionality (when a user requests appointments, he only receives appointments with his company id)

Wrote a rule:

```
match /appointments/{appointment} {
      allow write;
      allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.company_id == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company_id;
    }
```

But my code throw error about permissions

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'appointments'), where("company_id", "==", company_id), orderBy("createdAt"));
```

Comment: Have you made sure the requesting user is signed in, has a `company_id` property on their user data document, and is querying the correct `company_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't magically know what documents have what company_id, so it tries to read all documents to return the documents that you want, but it can't, your security rules stop it.

Either get rid of the security rules, or find a way to structure your database so that you don't have this problem.

I don't know enough about your database to tell you a good structure, but what about something like this?

- A collection called companies.
- Each document in the collection is a `company_id`
- A subcollection called users, where you put all users that belong to this company.
- Another subcollection, called appointments, where you put all appointments for the company.

That way, you could write a security rule like so:

```
match /companies/{company}/appointments/{appointment} {
  allow create: if true;
  allow read, update, delete: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)/users/$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, because we have divided all users and appointments into different collections, it will be impossible to query for all existing users or for all existing appointments.

It all depends on your use case.

Comment: But couldn't we use something like : 

```
allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.company_id == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company_id;
```

As this will allow users to read, update, delete appointments that have the same `company_id` as their own `company_id`.

Comment: I believe that something like that would work for querying specific document, but because he is trying to query the entire collection, firestore doesn't know which documents have a matching company id, it tries to read them all to check, but the rules stop firebase from doing so, at least that's what I think is causing the problem

Comment: That's really strange, because same mechanism but with auth.uid (resource.data.authorUid == request.auth.uid) worked perfectly.